# UML Class Diagram assosiation with following example?

Tags: uml

I need some help while doing some UML Class Diagram, with the following issue:

I have two classes:
Class: Person
Class: Team

What I want to show in UML is:

A person can be as Trainer in max one team.

[Edit: wrong: A team must not but can have max one person as role:Trainer.]

[Edit: changed: A team must have max one person as role:Trainer.]

A person can be a part of a team, as a role:Player.

A team does have at least 1 person, as a role:Player.

[image: uml]

Is this right? Or is there any other solution?

Edit:

I changed the diagram 
Here is my second version:

[uml, second version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhXpH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost:

1. Change multiplicity at Trainer association on Person side - put `0..1` (indicating there's at most one Person in a role Trainer). Currently you indicate a Team must have exactly one Trainer in contrary to yours:

> A team **must not** but can have max one person as role:Trainer.

2. You didn't indicate in how many Teams a Person can be a Player in a description. Currently you show that a Person must be a Player in at least on Team and can be a Player in many teams. Probably you should change multiplicity on association Player on Team side to:

   - `*` if a Person can be a Player of more than one team (but don't have to be a Player at all)
   - `0..1` if a Person can be a Player in **at most one** Team

Comment: Oh yes, you're right: "if a Person can be a Player of more than one team (but don't have to be a Player at all)" - My requirements were faulty, I corrected them (see above : "A team must have max one person as role:Trainer."). Thx

But how to write the Constraint in OCL? Do you have any Idea?

Comment: Multiplicity is itself limiting how many of specific objects can be associated in a certain role. You don't have to additionally add any constraints. A constraint is used if you need to add some additional limitation that cannot be expressed using multiplicity or in some other way. For example if the same person cannot be in a role of a Trainer and a Player then you should add a `xor` constraint. it can be in both roles simultaneously you don't have to do anything. Moreover I don't see any change in your requirements (I mean - semantically nothing changed in my opinion)

Comment: What if the Player is not allowed to be in the Team where he is a Trainer, this is a limitation for a constraint right?

Comment: Yes. Then you link both associations with a dashed line and put `{xor}` on it to indicate that specific constraint. Other option is to add regular note with a constraint in it with the same `{xor}` constraint and link such note to both associations. Both notations are semantically the same.

Comment: Sure. Remember to "thank" authors (not only in this question) whose response you see as helpful by upvoting the answer and the one answer that (best) solves your problem mark as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> A team must not but can have max one person as role:Trainer.

means that near the `Trainer` role you need a `0..1` multiplicity. Else it looks ok.

N.B. your rules don't tell whether one person can be `Player` and `Trainer` as well. If you need to express that, the simplest way it to add a constraint to either `Person` or the two associations.

Comment: thx, I did ad a constraint, a Person can be a Player and Trainer as well.

Comment: You need to enclose the constraint text in curly brackets `{ a person can .. }`

Comment: Thx you, how can I make the Constraint in OCL? any idea?

Comment: You won't need OCL. Plain text is fine. I have seen OCL only in academic circles and never in some production.